# notify user only once instead of every update in a website to prevent spamming of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

i have a applications running on `Rails 3.2.13` and `ruby 1.9.3 MRI`.The application allows users to upload multiple videos/songs/images and uses S3 for data storage.i am looking for a concept where for an upload of 100 videos(any n uploads),my registered user should get only one mail saying the count of uploads for videos/images/songs:-for example

***Hi mike,Please check for latest updates:-
 - n+ videos uploaded.
 - more than 50 songs uploaded .....etc***

so .***.i dont want to spam my users inbox with every notification mail***.Right now i can send email for every video/song/image uploaded using observers but what if there are thousands of uploads,so how i can get this thing working.

*I thought about it that i can write a logic to count an average of recent(daily/weekly/montly) uploads and then send that count in just one email instead of every update*.is it the correct way or is there any better way to notify user with some other logic...*(i was wondering how Youtube notifies its users if it want to for every uploads*..???)

Comment: The real question is when do you want to send the emails?  It is not very clear in the question.  Do you want to send it as soon as it reaches n, do you want to send it every n days or after every upload?

Comment: thanks @HithamS.AlQadheeb ..i  need to check n uploads ..if there are no n uploads then i will check for nos of days and notify the user for anything new ...i guess it should work on both scenarios...if first exists else second one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think about using filters / callbacks with `if` clause in model Upload, for example:

```
after_commit :send_notification, on: :create, 
           if: ->{ (Upload.count % 100) == 0) && self.status.was_not_sent?  }
# self is model instance variable here
```

Comment: thanks @Mihail Davydenkov,but will it work for all scenarios such as even if there is just 10 uploads in one week...???

Comment: then you probably should use gem `whenever` to send notifications to users every day/week. You can combine those strategies (callbacks and cron jobs)